# CouchDB appears to be uninstalled, but curl localhost:5984 still returns the "Welcome" document

Tags: couchdb

I had previously installed CouchDB via Homebrew, but my database got into a weird state so I had planned to wipe the slate clean and uninstall/reinstall.  I ran `brew uninstall couchdb`, however when I reinstalled it I ran into the same weird state issues as before.

I ran the uninstall command again and then ran `curl localhost:5984`, and to my surprise I see:

`{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"1316020b7ecc176ede36dc9acd8ea4e9","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"Homebrew","version":"1.6.1_13"}}`

The following is the output of running `brew list`:

```
ack         elixir          gnutls          libpng          node-build      pyenv-virtualenv    watchman
adns            erlang          heroku          libtasn1        nodenv          python          wget
autoconf        erlang@19       icu4c           libtiff         npth            python3         wireshark
autoconf-archive    etl         imagemagick     libtool         nspr            qt          wxmac
automake        fortune         jpeg            libunistring        oniguruma       qt5         xz
c-ares          freetype        jq          libusb          openssl         rbenv           yarn
cmake           gdbm            leiningen       libxml2         openssl@1.1     readline        zsh-completions
coreutils       geoip           libassuan       libyaml         p11-kit         redis
cowsay          gettext         libevent        memcached       pcre            rlwrap
dbus            git         libffi          mit-scheme      pinentry        ruby-build
docker          glib            libgcrypt       mongodb         pkg-config      spidermonkey
docker-compose      gmp         libgpg-error        nettle          postgresql      sqlite
docker-machine      gnupg           libksba         node            pyenv           the_silver_searcher
```

As you can see, CouchDB is not listed among the installed formulae.  I ran `brew uses couchdb` (which lists all formulae that have CouchDB as a dependency), and the only result was `couchdb-lucene`, which I don't have installed.

My question is, why is the `curl` command still returning a document if I have uninstalled CouchDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out running `brew uninstall <packagename>` doesn't kill any currently-running processes for that package.  I found and manually killed a running CouchDB process, and ran `ps aux | grep couchdb` a few times to verify the process didn't respawn.  When re-installing CouchDB I still have my same database state issues, but that's a topic for another post.